# Where to store user credentials in a Python desktop application?

Tags: python, security

I am writing a desktop application in Python. This application requires the user to input their GMail email and password (however an account must be created specifically for this app, so it's not their personal (read: important) GMail account). I was wondering what would be the best way to store those login credentials. I don't need it to be super secure, but would like something more than storing it as plain text.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you could not store the information on disk at all?  I think that's always the most secure approach, if you can manage it. Can you check the credentials and then discard that information?

You can always encrypt the information if that doesn't work, but the decryption mechanism and key would probably have to reside in your program, then.  Still, it might meet your criterion of not super-secure but better than plain text.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, as the credentials must be saved and be there once the program is closed and re-run.

Answer (score 1):

Use the OS keyring for this, which is the job of the [python-keyring](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring/#what-is-python-keyring-lib) module.

Answer (score 0):

Use the platform's native configuration storage mechanism (registry, GConf, plist).

Comment: Your question asks "where", not "how". Of course you want to obfuscate it somehow. But that does not affect "where".

Comment: -1. All recent OS have specialized mechanisme to store password that are willingly separated from the main one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Qt for your app, you should really use [QSettings](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html) and let the framework handle the storage for you. Note: QSettings will NOT encrypt anything for you, but will store values in the most appropriate location depending on the platform it's running on.

Regarding security, you really should use OAuth, like in the example [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/XoauthDotPyRunThrough), and just store the resulting token.